# Only one out of three checkboxes checked in each tr of atable with checkboxes can be checked with jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a table of checkboxes and I want only one out of three to be checked in each row. I wrote a code, it works great for every row but when I check a checkbox in the second row the first rows checkbox gets unchecked.

you can check the code on http://jsfiddle.net/annakoutli/Zp4d5/1/

here is the HTML

```
            <td class="col_featured-ad"><input type="checkbox" id="featured3_ad2" class="radio2 price featured3" value="featured3_ad2" name="featured_ad2" />
            </td>
            <td class="col_featured-ad"><input type="checkbox" id="featured7_ad2" class="radio2 price featured7" value="featured7_ad2" name="featured_ad2" />
              </td>
            <td class="col_featured-ad"><input type="checkbox" id="featured15_ad2" class="radio2 price featured15" value="featured15_ad2" name="featured_ad2" />
              </td>
          </tr>
```

and here is the jQuery

```
  $('input.radio1:checkbox').change(function(){
    var $group = $('input.radio1:checkbox');
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $group.not($(this)).attr('checked',false);
    }
});

$('input.radio2:checkbox').change(function(){
    var $group = $('input.radio2:checkbox');
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $group.not($(this)).attr('checked',false);
    }
});
```

Any suggestions? Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the usage of checkbox in place of radio buttons

```
$('input.radio2:checkbox').click(function(){
    var $chk = $(this), $group = $chk.closest('tr').find('input.radio2:checkbox');
    if(this.checked){
        $group.not(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Ur66t/)

Comment: +1 for giving a solution when dev should really shout at whoever doesn't understand radio buttons.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I made mine work as well you can check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/annakoutli/Zp4d5/2/

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you're using Checkboxes incorrectly. Checkboxes should be used to select multiple elements. If you only want one element to be selected then you should be using **radio buttons** which are explicitly designed for this case. Then you won't need to use any JavaScript.

Comment: Yes you are right about that, and I had that in mind. But that's not my call. I have to work with that

Comment: @user2693896 hah - OK, well Arun P Johny's solution is fine if you **really** need to use this, but I think you're better off instructing whoever designed this concept how radio buttons work.